# await function on ngOnInit returning undefined

Tags: angular, async-await

I am trying to get specific data before doing other functions as the other functions rely on that function to assign variables but I get an undefined error when refreshing but if I navigate to the place I need to be, It wont throw the undefined error, Here is my code:

```
public async ngOnInit() {
    const getdata = await this.websiteSettingsService.webConfig;
    this.getId(getdata);
    this.TournamentDetails = this.tournamentService.getMainTournamentDetails(this.leaderboardId).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
      shareReplay(1)
    );

    this.TournamentDetails.subscribe((response) => {
      this.getTournamentDetails(response);
    });
    }
  public getTournamentDetails(response: TournamentStatusModel) {
    this.TournamentStatus = response;

  }

  public getId(response: any) {
    response.forEach((ID) => {
      if (ID.settingName.includes('current_tournament')) {
        this.leaderboardId = ID.value;
      }
    });
  }
```

The error comes in my getId function saying `TypeError: can't access property "forEach", response is undefined`

But I am awaiting data first so I am confused as to why it is doing this

Comment: Can you show to us the webisteSettingsService code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try something like this. declare your async function inside ngOnInit and then immediately invoke it.

```
public ngOnInit() {
    (async () => {
        const getdata = await this.websiteSettingsService.webConfig;
        this.getId(getdata);
        this.TournamentDetails = this.tournamentService.getMainTournamentDetails(this.leaderboardId).pipe(
            takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
            shareReplay(1)
        );

        this.TournamentDetails.subscribe((response) => {
            this.getTournamentDetails(response);
        });
    })();
}
```